# Round arrow button surrounded with three break steps

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I'm working on a multi step form and it needs to have an arrow button surrounded by three steps (that is the number of pages) and each step is colored once its completed. I can see the horizontal step forms everywhere but these round arrow button with steps with space in between them is something I'm unable to find or make.[image: The type of button I'm trying to build] Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[react-circular-progressbar](https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-circular-progressbar) npm package has segmented circles and can take any JSX content as children (for your arrow icon). Following code is adapted from their [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vymm4oln6y):

```
   <CircularProgressbarWithChildren
      value={66.6}
      strokeWidth={10}
      styles={buildStyles({
         strokeLinecap: "butt"
      })}
   >
      <img
         style={{ width: 40, marginTop: -5 }}
         src="https://i.imgur.com/b9NyUGm.png"
         alt="doge"
      />
      <RadialSeparators
         count={3}
         style={{
            background: "#fff",
            width: "2px",
            // This needs to be equal to props.strokeWidth
            height: `${10}%`
         }}
      />
   </CircularProgressbarWithChildren>
```